# Why can we access the subroutine even after specifying it in EXPORT_FAIL?

Tags: perl

Why, even after specifying subtract function in `EXPORT_FAIL`, am I able to access the function by defining it fully like `mathematics::subtract`? How can we completely make the function private?

```
package mathematics;

use Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(add);
@EXPORT_FAIL = qw(subtract);

sub add() {
    print("you can add numbers here"."\n");
}

sub subtract() {
    print("you can subtract the numbers here"."\n");
}

1;
```

Answer (score 4):

> How can we completely make the function private???

You cannot. Perl doesn't have the concept of private or public.

You can however make it a lexical code reference and use that inside your code.

```perl
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $_private = sub {
  return "this is a secret";
};                               # note the semicolon

sub bar { 
  return $_private->();          # call with reference syntax ->()
}

1;
```

As a lexical variable, it is now only accessible from within its scope. In this case, that scope is the file, not the package. So if you have multiple packages in one file, they can all see it. You cannot access it via a fully qualified name from outside the package.

By convention, things that should be handled as if they were private in Perl are named with a leading underscore `_`. That's how other developers know that something is not part of the public API of a module and that it's subject to change and should not be messed with. Of course that doesn't stop anybody from doing it, but generally there is no reason to stop them.

Also note that package names in Perl typically are written in camel case with the first letter being capitalised. Your package should be called `Mathematics`, and it should have `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Comment: ` $_private->()`

Comment: @clamp yes, good catch, thanks. Feel free to edit something like this that is blatantly wrong yourself :)

Comment: Need a little more rep, until then edits go to the queue and cause even more work for others ;))

Comment: @clamp but it does also give you rep, and as the author I can directly accept it.

Answer (score 3):

From Perl 5.18, you can use lexical subroutines to achieve what you want. The [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Lexical-Subroutines) says this:

> These subroutines are only visible within the block in which they are
> declared, and only after that declaration:
>
> ```
> # Include these two lines if your code is intended to run under Perl
> # versions earlier than 5.26.
> no warnings "experimental::lexical_subs";
> use feature 'lexical_subs';
>
> foo();              # calls the package/global subroutine
> state sub foo {
>     foo();          # also calls the package subroutine
> }
> foo();              # calls "state" sub
> my $ref = \&foo;    # take a reference to "state" sub
>
> my sub bar {
>     ...
> }
> bar();              # calls "my" sub
> ```

p.s. Lexical subroutines are non-experimental from 5.26.